# можно ли в yii2 преобразовать массив или объект в xml?

Tags: php, yii2, xml

задача такая. надо выгружать данные из модели и передавать их по почте или выгружать в файл в формате xml. на вьюшке нормально все отображает, а в файле или на почте нет. туда уходят не преобразованные данные, а в виде массива или объекта.
подскажите какие есть средства по преобразованию данных в формат xml

Comment: с  помощью php, например, можно преобразовать данные в xml

Comment: Нынче сериализация не помогает?

Answer (score 3):

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_XML;
    $data = Model::getFields();
    return $data;
}
```